# PHP function fatal error:

Tags: php

I have 2 pages:

*automate.php
checkemail.php*

on *automate.php* is:

```
<?php include 'scripts/checkemail.php'; ?>
```

and:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists("sendemail"))
{
    function sendemail($email_to,$email_from,$email_subject,$email_body,$email_replyto,$cc='')
    {
        if(filter_var($email_to, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            require_once "/usr/local/lib/php/Mail.php";

            $from = $email_from;
            $to = $email_to;
            $subject = $email_subject;
            $body = $email_body;

            $host = "mail.domain.co.uk";
            $username = "sending@domain.co.uk";
            $password = "*********";

            $headers = array ('From' => $from,
              'To' => $to,
              'Cc' => $cc,
              'Subject' => $subject,
              'Content-type' => 'text/html');
            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
              array ('host' => $host,
             'auth' => true,
             'username' => $username,
             'password' => $password));

             $rec = $to.', '.$cc;

            $mail = $smtp->send($rec, $headers, $body);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

then on *checkemail.php* i am calling this function:

```
sendemail("techsupport@domain.co.uk","Support <no-reply@domain.co.uk>","Contact Not Found",$contact_not_found_email,"no-reply@domain.co.uk");
```

but i am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sendemail() in /home/integra/public_html/automate/scripts/checkemail.php on line 180
```

Comment: Try using `require` instead of `include` to be sure the file is found.

Comment: i have tried require_once and require and include_once but still the same error

Comment: You're including checkemail.php in automate.php. You define a sendmail function in automate.php, then try to call it in checkemail.php. How is this supposed to work ? You should include automate.php in checkmail.php, not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `sendemail()` is still not defined when you run `include`.

This is because the `if(!function_exists("sendemail"))` block will only execute AFTER the include, and thus, the function will not exist.